# How does one compare values in GAS assembly architecture?

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler

I'm having trouble finding an answer to this seemingly innocuous and simple question. I wish to use cmp or one of its derivatives (cmpl, cmpb, etc...) to compare two values in a GAS assembly program. The problem is, when I run multiple comparisons that should come out differently, they come out the same. I believe it involves my misunderstanding of how data is compared with the cmp operation.

Here is the situation:

I have a fill variable to take input like this, with a equ to hold the size:

```
buff:    .fill    20
         .equ     bufLen, .-buff
```

Then I put the bufLen variable in a register, and the comparison value in another:

```
         movl     $bufLen, %eax
         movl     $0x03, %ebx
```

Finally, I compare and if compare equal, jump to another line:

```
         cmpl     %eax, %ebx
         je       anotherplace
```

However, when I compare inputs of lengths 2 and 4, they both come out less than (I changed the je to jl for a quick debug). Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong or point me to a question I missed that might tell me how I messed up?

Just as a reminder, this is GAS assembly architecture.

All help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your whole code? At least [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)...

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar I suspected this initially as well, however since it didn't work when I tried "je", which wouldn't matter what order they're in, I am inclined to believe that the order of operations is incorrect. Additionally, my understanding of the order of operations matches your explanation.

Comment: @Enzo Ferber This is the complete entirety of relevant code. The creation of the buffer size variable, then comparing it to 3. Only thing missing is the usual formalities, like .globl _start and the .section .data up top.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Could you elaborate a bit? I'm afraid I'm quite new and am having difficulty fully understanding assembly. I was taught that you can use the variable name with either a $ or without, but what is the difference?

Comment: Actually I misread your code, forget you saw my comment

Comment: Did you oversee that AT&T syntax has the reversed order of the operands? `cmpl %eax, %ebx` in AT&T is equivalent to `cmp ebx, eax` in Intel syntax. So `jl` jumps, if `EBX` is less than `EAX`. `$bufLen` has a fix value and is always = 20.

Comment: @rkhb Oh it has a fixed length? I believe that was my problem right there. I was never explained in detail the idea of putting a .equ after the variable declaration, and assumed it properly adjusted the length to the input. How might I get the length of the input string proper?

Comment: This depends on the function you use for the input. Most likely the function returns the length of the input.

Comment: `buff: .fill    20` creates a buffer of 20 1 byte elements containing 0. `.equ     bufLen, .-buff` says that bufLen = the current address - the address of _buff_. That happens to equal the number of one byte elements specified in the _fill_ directive. If you were to change it to _.fill 21_ then _bufLen_ would have 21. bufLen will always have a fixed value.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Ah, so it just grabs it once. That makes more sense now. Could you tell me how I would determine the length of an input string? Like, say, with a predefined terminator character?

Comment: You have to scan down the array and look for the terminator character. You could use the `scas` instructions with a repeat like `REPNE SCAS`. See the instruction set reference http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_279.html .  You'd put bufLen in _CX_ (the length of the array), the terminator character in   _AL_ and set ES:EDI to point to _buff_

Comment: @MichaelPetch I'm not using the x86 architecture, I'm in GAS. Is the command the same across both platforms? I can't find that method documented in GNU assembly.

Comment: GAS and Intel syntax that you are viewing are for the x86 instruction set. Things are just specified differently. For the most part Intel doesn't use a % in front of register (GAS does) and most importantly the operands are reversed. More on the differences can be found here: http://repo.hackerzvoice.net/depot_madchat/coding/asm/att-vs-intel.txt

Comment: Ah ok, I wanted to make sure it would work on my linux VM. I will try that command, and if I continue to have issues I'll probably create a question that is more specific about the exact issue I run into. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: In AT&T syntax you'd be using `SCASB` (B on the end means you are dealing with bytes). SCASW would be for Words (16bit), SCASD would be a double word (32 bits)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments, I show you some ways to get the length of a zero-terminated string (`.asciz`) in Linux:

**witch.s:**

```
.data

witches: .asciz "Double, double toil and trouble; Fire burn, and cauldron bubble"
format0: .asciz "%s\n"
format1: .asciz "Return of printf: %u\n"
format2: .asciz "Return of strlen: %u\n"
format3: .asciz "Return of repne scasb: %u\n"

.text
.global main
main:

    push $witches
    push $format0
    call printf         # returns in EAX the amount of printed chars (+ \n!)
    add $8, %esp

    push %eax
    push $format1
    call printf
    add $8, %esp

    push $witches
    call strlen         # returns in EAX the length of the string
    add $4, %esp

    push %eax
    push $format2
    call printf
    add $8, %esp

    mov $witches, %edi
    xor %al, %al
    xor %ecx, %ecx
    dec %ecx
    repne scasb
    neg %ecx            # returns in ECX the length of the string + 2

    push %ecx
    push $format3
    call printf
    add $8, %esp

    mov $0, %eax        # return 0;
    ret
```

**Compile & run:**

```
gcc -m32 witch.s
./a.out
```

There are more ways

Comment: Usually for `repne scasb` to get the equivalent of strlen I'd use `not %ecx` and then do `dec %ecx` (if I'm excluding the terminator from the string length)

Answer (score 0):

As discovered in the comments on my original question, the issue was that I didn't realize bufLen was 20 long, as was defined in the buff variable. Therefore, all the lower values I compared it against were returned as less than 20.